# Dropdown for GitHub Workflows input parameters

Tags: github-actions, github-api, building-github-actions

I want to create a dropdown list for my GitHub Action Input parameter. This should help in selecting a value from the dropdown just like how the option is there to select the branches.

Comment: This is no such feature in GitHub actions yet.

Comment: @MohammadDohadwala there is now.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

When using `workflow_dispatch`, [it's now possible](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-10-github-actions-input-types-for-manual-workflows/) to have `choice`, `boolean` and `environment` inputs instead of only just strings. `choice` is a dropdown, `boolean` is a checkbox and `environment` is like `choice` but will auto-populate with all environments configured in your repos settings.

[Here's an example workflow](https://github.com/jonas-lomholdt/input-types/blob/main/.github/workflows/inputs.yml) using the new types:

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        type: environment
        description: Select the environment
      boolean:
        type: boolean
        description: True or False
      choice:
        type: choice
        description: Make a choice
        options:
        - foo
        - bar
        - baz
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: greet
        run: | 
          echo "environment is ${{ github.event.inputs.environment }} / ${{ inputs.environment }}"
          echo "boolean is ${{ github.event.inputs.boolean }}" / ${{ inputs.boolean }} 
          echo "choice is ${{ github.event.inputs.choice }}" / ${{ inputs.choice }}
```

Note that inputs [can now be accessed directly using the `inputs` context](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-06-10-github-actions-inputs-unified-across-manual-and-reusable-workflows/), instead of using `github.event.inputs`.

[image: example-of-the-workflow]

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot :) Can I load/pass the parameters using the JSON file ?

Comment: I'm actually unsure when variable substitution will happen in the workflows lifetime. So I'm not convinced that would work. But you should definitely give it a try!

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-usage-of-the-inputs-context-in-a-manually-triggered-workflow do you know why github recommends using `inputs.inputname` and not `github.event.inputs.inputname`? Are they equivalent?

Comment: @walnut_salami Yes they are equivalent. This is because they unified the way you access inputs so it's the same across workflows triggered manually using `workflow_dispatch` and workflows called by another workflow using `workflow_call`. See this blog post for reference: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-06-10-github-actions-inputs-unified-across-manual-and-reusable-workflows/

Comment: What about populating the choice programmatically or  another way to input in one of the steps?

Comment: @LuisMauricio as far as I know that is not possible.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to have multiple values for a single option - an object maybe ? is this possible ?

Comment: As far as I know that's not possible at the moment.

Comment: `inputs.inputname` and not `github.event.inputs.inputname` are not always the same. For example, suppose a dispatched workflow calls an action. The workflow and the action has different inputs. When you reference `inputs.inputname` and `github.event.inputs.inputname` inside the aciton. `inputs.inputname` will the be the inputs of the action, and `github.event.inputs.inputname` will be the inputs of the worflow.

Comment: @JonasLomholdt From where does the dropdown list for `environment` get populated? Mine shows an empty dropdown list.

Comment: @OldGeezer it's populated from the deployment environments that you define (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment). Environments are only available in public repos and paid plans.